# Could gravitational waves have their origin in collision of true and false vacuum?

Tags: cosmology, vacuum, gravitational-waves, big-bang, bubbles

Could the gravitational waves the consequence of the collision between a true vacuum bubble and a false vacuum bubble, at the beginning of the universe?

(as they try to explain there:
https://www.futura-sciences.com/sciences/actualites/univers-cosmologie-pourra-t-on-voir-naissance-masse-particules-52505/)

Comment: *the gravitationnal waves* Are you talking about the ones that LIGO detects?

Comment: I am talking about *any* gravitational wave. Not necessary those of LIGO/Virgo.

Comment: What is a false vacuum bubble? (This question might be answered in the reference you cited, but I don't read French.) I did find the following: https://medium.com/the-infinite-universe/the-universe-may-be-a-false-vacuum-bubble-961e1a177e52. What I do not understand is what this concept has to do with gravitational waves.